# Issue with the file path in DRACOLoader() to load a Compressed glb/gltf model into the threejs scene

Tags: three.js

Here I'm trying to add one compressed gltf/glb model into my scene(for uncompressed models in which DRACOloader is not needed and working fine, but for compressed models which are needed and the file path issue), I'm facing one issue with DRACOLoader in threeJS,  Which is used to decode the compressed model when we load it to the threeJS, In here I need to load the Decoder file path, here I'm using the angular 13 and threejs

```
    const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();
    dracoLoader.setDecoderPath('jsm/libs/draco/');      //here I'm adding the path
    dracoLoader.setDecoderConfig( { type: 'js' } );
    
    // Load your GLB model using GLTFLoader
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();

    // Load a compressed model using the Draco loader
    loader.setDRACOLoader(dracoLoader);
    loader.load('assets/pharmaceutical-company.gltf', (gltf) => {
      const model = gltf.scene;
      scene.add(model);
      // Loop through the nodes in the model
      model.traverse((node: any) => {
        // if (node instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
          console.log(node)
          console.log(node.name)
          // Create the HTML element
          const element = document.createElement('div');
          element.className = 'htmlElement';
          element.textContent = node.name;
          element.style.color = 'red'
          element.style.cursor = 'pointer'
          // Add click functionality
          element.addEventListener('', ()=>{})
          element.addEventListener('click', () => {
            // Callback function to execute when the element is clicked
            console.log('Element clicked!');
          });

          // Create a CSS2DObject and set its position
          const css2DObject = new CSS2DObject(element);
          css2DObject.position.copy(node.position);

          // Add the CSS2DObject to the CSS3DRenderer
          scene.add(css2DObject);
          if(node.name == 'grab_2'){
            // Create the ECharts chart
            const mainChartContainer = document.createElement('div');
            mainChartContainer.style.padding = '10px';
            mainChartContainer.style.backgroundColor = '#F86F03';
            const chartElement = document.createElement('div');
            chartElement.style.width = '300px';
            chartElement.style.backgroundColor = '#2E4F4F';
            chartElement.style.height = '240px';
            const chart = echarts.init(chartElement);
            chart.setOption({
              title: {
                text: 'Pie Chart'
              },
              series: [
                {
                  name: 'Pie Chart',
                  type: 'pie',
                  data: [
                    { value: 335, name: 'Category 1' },
                    { value: 310, name: 'Category 2' },
                    { value: 234, name: 'Category 3' },
                    { value: 135, name: 'Category 4' },
                    { value: 1548, name: 'Category 5' }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            });
            mainChartContainer.appendChild(chartElement)

            // Create a CSS2DObject and set its position
            const css2DChartObject = new CSS2DObject(mainChartContainer);
            console.log(node.position)
            css2DChartObject.position.copy(node.position);
  
            // Add the CSS2DObject to the CSS3DRenderer
            scene.add(css2DChartObject);
          }
        // }
      });
    });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKAIP.png)

expecting the correct path to mention the file path to the draco one

Comment: The error is telling you that the relevant files cannot be found. Make sure that the path is correct!

Comment: Thanks for the response, Actually the file and the path are correct, and it's there but showing this error.

Answer (score 0):

Oftentimes, the Draco decoder files exist somewhere in your `node_modules` directory. By default, the path is something along the lines of `/examples/jsm/libs/draco/`, but your webserver isn't serving that directory (which is good!).

The quickest way to set this up is to download the draco directory from the [three.js sourcecode](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/jsm/libs/draco).

- Place these files in your webservers public directory, e.g. serve it under `/draco`.
- Point the Draco loader decoderPath to it: `setDecoderPath('/draco')`.

You can also get the latest DRACO files from Google's [Draco Repository](https://github.com/google/draco).